# Make buffered channel after channel variable initialisation

Tags: go, memory-management, channel

I can initialise a buffered string channel like this

```
queue := make(chan string, 10)
```

But how to initialise a buffered channel in a struct in Go ? Basically I want to allocate memory to a buffered string channel. But initially in the struct I would just define it and in struct initialisation, I would like to allocate memory to it

```
type message struct {

  queue *chan string
// or will it be 
//queue []chan string

}

func (this *message) init() {

  queue = make(chan string,10)

  this.queue = &queue

}
```

Comment: Don't call your receiver `this`.  Give it a meaningful name. The first letter of the type is common, so `m` in your case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do this:

```
type message struct {
   queue chan string
}

func (m *message) init() {
    m.queue = make(chan string, 10)
}
```

There's no need to take the address of the channel in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

The same way:

```
type message struct {
    queue chan string
}

func (m *message) init() {
    m.queue = make(chan string, 10)
}
```

But you seem to be a bit confused about what a channel is.  `*chan string` is a valid construct in Go, but usually unnecessary.  Just use a normal `chan string`--no need for a pointer.

> // or will it be
>   //queue []chan string

This would be an array of channels, which is also valid, but not what you want in this case.

A channel is not an array. It's more like a stream (as you might get when you read a file, or a network connection). But don't take that analogy too far, either.